# R data.table replace "NULL" with `NA` when columns are factors

Tags: r, data.table

I pulled some data from a SQL database through ODBC and the columns are automatically set to `factor`. It is something like the following:

```
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(sqlQuery(channel, query))
```

My data looks like this, just with a lot more columns:

```
data <- data.table("C1"=as.factor(c(letters[1:4], "NULL", letters[5])),
                   "C2"=as.factor(c(rnorm(3), "NULL", rnorm(2))),
                   "C3"=as.factor(c(letters[1], "NULL", letters[2:4], "NULL")))
> data
     C1                 C2   C3
1:    a -0.190200079604691    a
2:    b  0.310548914832963 NULL
3:    c 0.0153099116493453    b
4:    d               NULL    c
5: NULL  0.157187027626419    d
6:    e  0.118537540781528 NULL
> str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ C1: Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 6 5
 $ C2: Factor w/ 6 levels "-0.190200079604691",..: 1 5 2 6 4 3
 $ C3: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 5 2 3 4 5
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

How can I replace the "NULL" with `NA`? Here I want `R` to treat these SQL "NULL" strings as missing values `NA`. I tried the following, but seems `NA` causes problems.

```
for (col in names(data)) {
  set(data, which(data[[col]]=="NULL"), col, NA)
}

> Error in set(data, which(data[[col]] == "NULL"), col, NA) : 
  Can't assign to column 'C1' (type 'factor') a value of type 'logical' (not character, factor, integer or numeric)
```

**RODBC Solution**

Thanks to @user20650's suggestion, you can control missing values from `sqlQuery` by doing `data <- data.table(sqlQuery(channel, query, na.strings=c("NA", "NULL")))`. However, it is still possible to have this problem if your data source is formatted incorrectly, so this is not an universal solution to the post.

Comment: Please note that "NULL" is not `NULL`

Comment: @BondedDust Yes, in my data, "NULL" is a string pulled from SQL. I want R to replace them as missing values.

Comment: `data[data=="NULL"] <- NA` (not sure if this is good practive for data.tables)

Comment: I don't know why the answer to this question was deleted. It was correct.

Comment: @ssdecontrol I think the OP wants to check for NA using `is.na(data$C1)` which returns FALSE

Comment: @akrun really? `is.na(NA_character_)` returns TRUE for me.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Within the `factor` class, I am getting all FALSE. but if I convert to character class, it returns TRUE.  Not sure if that is a bug or not.

Comment: @akrun wow, you're right. I'd imagine that's a bug.

Comment: Factors in R get to be exceptional / break every rule of the language and human intuition. So, probably not a bug.

Comment: Can you not use `na.strings = c("NA", "NULL")` or similar, in the `sqlQuery` so that the values are set to missing while reading in

Comment: The mode of factors is `integer` so the replacement would need to be with `NA_integer_`. A better approach would be to coerce to one of character or real.

Comment: @user20650 That's a good point. I will try that.

Comment: it's very strange. Usually sqlQuery maintain SQL column classes, don't know why you have all `as.factor`

Comment: @AndriyTkachenko Maybe `data <- data.table(mydata)` does it?

Comment: Is it not likely due the presence of a character NULL string converting  the vectors to character ... then the default is to convert to factors??

Comment: @Frank sqlQuery returns data.frame with no changes. And if data.table seems to be an improvement to basic data.frame it shouldn't  do this factor conversion

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has the desired effect and is much more compact:

```
is.na(data) <- data == "NULL"
```

Note re: comment Q: the `is.na` function is quite different than the `is.na<-` function. The latter one used here is an assignment of a value of NA to items that are defined by the logical expression on hte RHS of the assigment operator. There is an `is.na.data.frame`-method but not an `is.na[<-.dataframe`-method. So not really sure if this is a purely by-reference strategy, since it is not implemented with the `[.data.frame` syntax. It may be using "is.na<-.default".

I think after noodling around a bit more that "is.na<-.default" (which is just `{x[value] <- NA; x}` ) so will end up dispatching this call to `[<-.data.table` so it probably will be done "by reference".

Comment: Could someone explain how to read that? explain what it means? 
My read is that is.na(data) returns a similar structure with T or F values depending on is.na().  data == '"NULL" seems to do the same thing, so it's not clear what the assignment does.

Comment: It’s setting any position in ‘data’ that equals the string “NULL” to instead be an NA_character value. Remember that in R, “NULL” is not the same as NULL.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
data[,names(data):=lapply(.SD,function(x){
  z <- levels(x)
  z[z=="NULL"] <- NA
  `levels<-`(x,z)
})]
```

To see what happened, look at `lapply(data,levels)` and you'll see that `"NULL"` is gone.

---

(Thanks, @akrun:) A more concise and intuitive variant is available using the `car` package:

```
library(car)
data[,names(data):=lapply(.SD, recode, '"NULL"=NA')]
```

---

In the `data.table` world, it's usually possible to modify by reference. In this case, that looks like...

```
for (j in names(data)) setattr(data[[j]],"levels",{
  z <- levels(data[[j]])
  z[z=="NULL"] <- NA
  z
})
```

This avoids making a copy of the whole vector, as `` `levels<-` `` does.

Comment: Can someone remind me why this wasn't done: `is.na(data) <- data == "NULL"`

Comment: I posted similar above @BondedDust; the issue i think is that NULL is still a level., so droplevels, or similar needs to be used

Comment: @BondedDust I didn't think of it, nor see it in the comments higher up. I only use factors for tabulation, so I'm not really up on this stuff. Seems like a good way to go. Modifying the levels by reference might be a *little* better if the vectors are large or something, but `\`is.na<-\`` is clearest if it works.

Comment: I strongly suspect there is a `is.na<-.data.table` function.

Comment: @BondedDust Is that comma in your last comment a typo? I've seen commas in `methods` lists and never knew what to make of them.

Comment: Typo (fixed), and when I checked I could not find it `methods('is.na<-')`

Comment: Nonetheless, `is.na(data) <- data == "NULL"` works fine (having almost the same result as the code in my answer). I'm not sure which method is called. You could post that as an answer, I think.

Comment: Another option would be `library(car);data[, lapply(.SD, recode, '"NULL"=NA')]` which will automatically drop the levels and maintain a TRUE `NA`

Comment: @BondedDust & akrun: I think those are good answers (certainly better than mine in terms of conciseness) and might be more easily found by folks if posted as answers. Speaking of conciseness, I'll try switching to using `replace`

Comment: Scratch that; couldn't figure it out. Anyway, feel free to edit if you see possible improvements here.

Comment: @Frank You can add that in your solution.  I have deleted/undeleted a couple of times now :-)

Comment: I don't have any modifications to offer but was wondering after reading your code whether the `fread` facility could be interposed between an SQL db and R to magically do its column-typing.

Comment: @BondedDust Ah, could be. That's part of the data.table-verse I haven't used.