# Creating a loop in R to clean multiple datasets

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

Suppose I have the following dataframes (essentially 4 similar datasets):

```
q1_hosp <- data.frame(dxe1 = c(1,NULL, NA, NULL, 1), dxe2 = c(1,NULL, NULL, NULL, 1))
q2_hosp <- data.frame(dxe1 = c(NULL,1, 1, NA, 1), dxe2 = c(1,1, 1, NULL, 1))
q3_hosp <- data.frame(dxe1 = c(NA,NULL, 1 1, 1), dxe2 = c(1,NA, NA, NULL, 1))
q4_hosp <- data.frame(dxe1 = c(1,1, 1 NULL, 1), dxe2 = c(1,NULL, 1, 1, 1))
```

What I would like is to turn the NULL entries into missing values in R. I can do them by writing the following codes in a tedious manner:

```
any(is.na(q1_hosp$dxe1)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q1_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q1_hosp$dxe1, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
any(is.na(q1_hosp$dxe2)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q1_hosp$dxe2 <- na_if(q1_hosp$dxe2, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA

any(is.na(q2_hosp$dxe1)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q2_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q2_hosp$dxe1, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
any(is.na(q2_hosp$dxe2)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q2_hosp$dxe2 <- na_if(q2_hosp$dxe2, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA

any(is.na(q3_hosp$dxe1)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q3_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q3_hosp$dxe1, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
any(is.na(q3_hosp$dxe2)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q3_hosp$dxe2 <- na_if(q3_hosp$dxe2, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA

any(is.na(q4_hosp$dxe1)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q4_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q4_hosp$dxe1, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
any(is.na(q4_hosp$dxe2)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
q4_hosp$dxe2 <- na_if(q4_hosp$dxe2, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
```

What I would like is to create a loop so that the process is less tedious.

I have been trying with this

```
  for(i in 1:4) {
  ##Clean the dxe variables
  any(is.na(q[i]_hosp$dxe1)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
  q[i]_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q[i]_hosp$dxe1, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
 any(is.na(q[i]_hosp$dxe2)) # there are missing rows, keep NAs
  q[i]_hosp$dxe1 <- na_if(q[i]_hosp$dxe2, "NULL") #convert NULLto NA
}
```

But my code doesn't work and I am getting errors. Can anyone help write the for loop for what I want to achieve?

Comment: Use lists of frames, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227. `q[i]_host` will not work, that is looking for a vector or list `q` to find the `i`th element, and they will get a parsing error because of `_host`. I suggest you put your frames into a list-of-frames, as it will make many operations done on one frame easy to do on all frames (at once).

Comment: This is more efficient https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810681/r-data-table-replace-null-with-na-when-columns-are-factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the data in a list and use `lapply` to change `'NULL'` to `NA` from each of the dataframe.

```
result <- lapply(mget(sprintf('q%d_hosp', 1:4)), function(x) {x[x == 'NULL'] <- NA;x})
```

If you want the changes in individual dataframes back.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks. `list2evn` is useful. Learn a lot from you.

Comment: @Ronak Shah So for the actual dataset, I am having trouble getting the NAs if I use your code above. Suppose I have a variable dxe1 that is common in all datasets and I want to convert all the NULLs to NAs in the four datasets q1_hosp, q2_hosp, q3_hosp, q4_hosp. What is the role of 'x' in your code? I got the data in a list using 
q1_hosp <- list(q1_hosp). Named the list and the dataframe the same.

Comment: Btw dxe1 is a character variable

Comment: `x` is the individual dataframe in each iteration. So if you only want to change `dx1` column in your dataframes. `cols <- c('dx1')` and `result <- lapply(mget(sprintf('q%d_hosp', 1:4)), function(x) {x[cols][x[cols] == 'NULL'] <- NA;x})` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. all names of dataset are stored in `dl`, which can access with `get` function
2. `RMNULL` function is used to replace `NULL` by `NA`
3. `lapply` function is used to loop all datasets

```
# dataset name list 
dl <- sprintf("%s%s%s","q",1:2,"_hosp")
df.list <- lapply(dl,get)

# replace NULL with NA
## remove NULL function
RMNULL <- function(df){
    is.na(df) <- df == "NULL"
    return(df)
}
lapply(df.list, RMNULL)
```

example data:

```
q1_hosp <- structure(list(x = 1:3, y = list(NULL, NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("x",  "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

q2_hosp <- structure(list(x = 4:6, y = list(1, NULL, NULL)), .Names = c("x",  "y"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```